# delphi standalone webservice returns http error when consumed through php

Tags: web-services, delphi, nusoap

I'm pretty new in WS programming.
I created WS (that I picked the base from http://www.digicoast.com/delphi_soap_standalone.html) using delphi-7
When I consumed it through XAMPP php nusoap that is installed to my PC, it worked well and I got the requested result.
But when I consumed it through php nusoap on my web hosting, it returned nothing.
When I put debug in the php codes, it says: HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server. Error(110): Connection timed out.
Here is my php codes:

```
    <?php
    require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');
    $aparams = 'kode_query='.'TRIPS_ALL'.'&'.
               'kode_user='.$username.'&'.
               'kode_id='.$uid;
    $client = new nuSoap_Client('http://110.139.181.78:9696/wsdl/IVSoftWS');
    $xml_data = $client->call('GetXMLDataTable',$aparams);
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Error</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getError(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Info: my web hosting using php 5.2.9, while my XAMPP using php 5.3.1
Question: How can I get the same result through web hosting php codes?
Any helps are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the firewall settings? The server seems to run on port 9696, this port needs to be opened on the server (more precise: the server which runs the Delphi 7 web service server app) for incoming connections.

To verify, you can use a web browser (or [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)) from a different computer, and try to open the service URL.

Comment: thanks. But as I mentioned, I have no problem on accessing the same WS from my PC with XAMPP. The firewall is fine, as I can get the result from my PC.

Comment: maybe the firewall is configured to accept requests from specific IP address ranges only. can you ping or telnet to the web service from the web hosting environment?

Comment: yes, I tried using other computer (with XAMPP and WAMP) with different connection, and I found it worked fine as well. Seems to be no problem with firewall. But, I didn't try to ping/telnet from the web hosting. I'm not sure how to do that. FYI, the web hosting cpanel version: Pro 1.0(RC1). Your help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check using ping and telnet from all other servers to the web service server and it worked, but only from the PHP web hosting server it failed? Then it could be a firewall setting on the PHP web hosting server for outgoing connections, have you checked this? For example, can you access other web pages on port 80, 8080 or non-standard ports from within the PHP script?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I contacted the web hosting and they opened port 9696 for both incoming and outgoing, but I got same result when trying the web service.

Comment: there was suggestion to turn ON the SELinux to make the webservice working, but my Web Hosting refused it with reason that cPanel requires to DISABLE the SELinux.